# display date in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

In my XML File I have as the following :

```
<From year="2013" month="--01" day="---04"/>
```

In My XSLT File I want to display the values of these attributes, so I will have something like this in the output :

```
04/01/2013
```

But instead of this, I have this :

```
---01/--04/2013
```

This is what I wrote in my XSLT file :

```
<xsl:value-of select="Period/To/@day" />/<xsl:value-of select="Period/To/@month" />/<xsl:value-of select="Period/To/@year" />
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `translate()` to remove the`-`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(Period/To/@day,'-','')" />/
<xsl:value-of select="translate(Period/To/@month,'-','')" />/
<xsl:value-of select="Period/To/@year" />
```

Result:

```
04/01/2013
```

`translate(value, '-','')` just translates/replaces every occurence of `-` with nothing.

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/translate